# How to pass unicode value to a controller function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing a parameter to my codeigniter function in unicode but it is unable to store it in to the variable. It is showing the value in the javascript variable properly but not in the controller function parameter. If I pass a value other than unicode than its working properly.

here is my code:
view page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#search").click(function(){ 
         if ($('#search_key').val()=="")
            var user_id ="srch";
         else
            var user_id = $('#search_key').val();
             alert(user_id);
window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url("units/keyword"); ?>/"+user_id);


    });
}); 
</script>
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function keyword($s)
    {
        echo $s;
}
```

Comment: this should work ,may be a typo, did u get any error?. Make sure controller name is correct

Comment: `user_id` must be url-encoded

Comment: Can u tell me by example please

Comment: No error is there even when I pass non unicode value then its working properly.

Comment: Thanks its working using url encoded. Thanks for ur support

Comment: Its working properly on local machine but not on server